# "listen" for changes on slider / text field and update second text field

Tags: jquery, math, field

I have two sliders which update the amount in text fields, one for amount and one for deposit. I have done the following (i'm sure this is long winded and there is a better way of doing it):

```
var amount = $("input[name='amount']").val();
var amountdiv = amount.substring(1, amount.length);
var depositper = amountdiv / 100 * 20
$(depositper).prepend('&pound;');
$("input[name='deposit']").val(depositper);
```

However it only works upto the point of working out 20% of the amount field as I can't seem to get the prepend part right before setting the deposit field (substr and prepend are to remove then re-add the pound sign so the math can happen). Also I'd like it to dynamically change as the values update in the amount field - is this possible?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use string concatenation or [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to prepend the pound symbol.

As far as having it change with each time the amount changes, you could put your "recalculation" into a function, and call that function each time the amount value changes.

I've replaced your substring with `replace(/#/g, '')`, which will remove all pound symbolds from the string. With this method, the calculation will still work if only a number is entered in the `amount` field.

```js
function calculateDeposit() {
  var amount = $("input[name='amount']").val();
  var amountdiv = amount.replace(/#/g, '');     //remove all # symbols
  var depositper = `#${amountdiv / 100 * 20}`;  //prepend # (see Template Literals documentation above)

  $("input[name='deposit']").val(depositper);
}

$("input[name='amount']").change(calculateDeposit); //When the amount field changes, call calculateDeposit()
```

```css
input { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Amount: <input type="text" name="amount" />
Deposit: <input type="text" name="deposit" />
```

If you'd prefer that the deposit get updated with each keypress, then you can change the event listener from the `.change()` event to the `.keyup()` event.

Comment: That works in the sense that if a user typed the number into the field but it's actually done using the sliders - dragging them autofills the text field and thus this doesnt have any affect

Comment: You haven't included the code/markup for the sliders, nor given any detail other than "there are sliders". You can't get much more of an answer without providing more detail about the sliders - Are you using a plugin, how are you initializing them in the JavaScript, etc. Most slider implementations have some sort of `onChange` callback that you could use instead.